# Google SMTP service daily limit

Tags: django, smtp, gmail

I am using Google's **SMTP** service `(smtp.gmail.com)` in my Django project for sending account activation emails for new users.

I have went through [this page](https://support.google.com/a/answer/166852?hl=en) but not quite sure what exactly is Google's SMTP outgoing quota per day with regard my gmail account's setup. I am using only a regular Gmail account *(it's not subscribed to any of Google's premium services)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a few words, Google is never going to release this information to the public as it would be counter productive to their efforts in fighting mass spam emailing.

Perhaps the following article may clarify this for you a bit further.

https://www.serversmtp.com/limits-of-gmail-smtp-server/

Comment: Thank you so much, this is the most accurate answer I've got so far about this very concern.